# Prove that the fixed point iteration converges for the following continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

> Let $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such
>   that:
>
> $$-x+\beta  < \phi(x)<x, \quad \text{for} \quad x>\frac{\beta}{2}$$
>
> $$x <  \phi(x) < -x+\beta, \quad \text{for} \quad  
>  x<\frac{\beta}{2}.$$
>
> Show that the sequence $x_{n+1} = \phi(x_n)$ converges to
>   $\frac{\beta}{2}$, for all $x_0$.

I was able to prove that

$$ \bigg| \phi(x)-\frac{\beta}{2}\bigg| < \bigg| x-\frac{\beta}{2}\bigg| \quad \text(1)$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R} - \{\frac{\beta}{2}\}$, using the given inequalities.

Also, I could prove that $\phi\big(\frac{\beta}{2}\big) = \frac{\beta}{2}$ is the only fixed point of $\phi$ using that $\phi$ is continuous and the given inequalities. From (1), we can conclude that:

$$\bigg| x_{n+1}-\frac{\beta}{2}\bigg| < \bigg| x_{n}-\frac{\beta}{2}\bigg|.$$

Therefore, the sequence $e_n = |x_n-\frac{\beta}{2}| $ is monotone and bounded so it converges.

However, i'm having problems with showing that $e_n \to 0$. I tried by contradiction but it is not clear for me how to do it.

I appreciate any ideas or hints. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are close.  If $e_n$ were to converge to a nonzero value, there would be a second fixed point of $\phi(x)$. But you have shown otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The argument by contradiction should be fairly straightforward. Assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty} e_n = e \neq 0$. Continuity of $\phi$ then implies that $\phi(\frac{\beta}{2}+e) = \frac{\beta}{2}+e$ which cannot be due to the definition of $\phi$.

Comment: I can't see why the continuity of $\phi$ implies $\phi(\frac{\beta}{2} + e) = \frac{\beta}{2} + e$. The continuity implies $\phi(\frac{\beta}{2} + e_n)  \to  \phi(\frac{\beta}{2} + e)$. How can I conclude that  $\phi(\frac{\beta}{2} + e) = \frac{\beta}{2} + e$?

Comment: By definition of the sequence we have $x_{n+1} = \phi (x_{n})$. Passing to the limit using the continuity of $\phi$ gives the stated equality. Hope this clarifies.